# LibreOffice lock files and Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, libreoffice

I use Dropbox for collaborative work between Windows workstations. One of the use is to share LibreOffice documents. Concurrent editings are normally forbidden by LibreOffice by creating a lock file like : ".~lock.notes code.odt#" for the file "notes code.odt". However, when I edit a file, I see this lock file locally, but  not in the Dropbox web interface, and my coworkers do not see them in their own Dropbox.

Is there something to setup to have those files visible to everyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dropbox, they don't synchronize those files because they look different across operating systems. The solution would be to get the LibreOffice team to use plain file names and visible files for their locking scheme.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: It would require some modifications to LibreOffice, and I have no idea how to get that to happen.

Comment: @TomHaws, Do you have a source for the info in you post (that it's not synced for this reasons)? I'm very interested in this subject and would like to read what Dropbox has got to say.

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver, I only have private email and phone conversations with Dropbox technical support. I could help you track it down again if you want to. Dropbox has changed a lot since I posted this answer.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs, a good example of how to do that is the DWG file locking system used by Autodesk for AutoCAD. AutoCAD dwg files, while open, have always had a plain text lock file with a dwl extension. This was later supplemented with a dwl2 xml file. This works with Dropbox. https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/DWL-and-DWL2-files-are-created-while-working-on-AutoCAD.html

Comment: @TomHaws, I see. Don’t bother with that. However, the problem is present today.

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver, yes, it is. I can confirm that.